# Troubleshooting Hibernate error: referencedColumnNames not mapped to a single property

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

Title: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames not mapped to a single property

Description:
I'm encountering an error while working with Hibernate in my project. The error message is as follows:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(meta_id) of umun.wordpress.post.meta.WpPostMetaPref.wpPostMeta referencing umun.wordpress.post.meta.WpPostMeta not mapped to a single property
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:320) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1786) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1730) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
```

I'm using Hibernate in combination with Spring Framework, and this error occurs during the application startup. It mentions an `AnnotationException` related to `referencedColumnNames` not being mapped to a single property in the `umun.wordpress.post.meta.WpPostMetaPref.wpPostMeta` class.

I have already checked my mapping configurations and ensured that the necessary annotations are present. However, I'm unable to figure out what's causing this issue.

I have reviewed my Hibernate mapping configurations and ensured that the necessary annotations are present. I have also checked the database schema to verify the column mappings. However, despite these checks, I'm still encountering the error.

here is my code snippet

```
@Entity
@IdClass(WpPostMetaPrefId.class)
public class WpPostMetaPref extends EntityPref {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "meta_Id")
    private Long wpPostMetaId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "meta_Id", referencedColumnName = "meta_id",
            insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private WpPostMeta wpPostMeta;
```

I expect Hibernate to successfully create the entity mappings and establish the necessary relationships without any exceptions being thrown.

Remember to provide any additional relevant details or code snippets that might be helpful for others to understand and troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: how does `WpPostMeta` class look?